# How to logic: most commonly used inputs in succession

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance, google-apps-script

I've a input box with autocomplete (JQuery) and thousands of options (6000+), what I want is for the input box automatically 'suggest' the most commonly used option, after a option has been just inserted.

Ex.

1st time using, inputs

> Tomato
>  Orange
>  Tomato
>  Apple
>  Tomato
>  Orange

Now the second time using, when I type Tomato, I want a function to retrieve Orange, which was typed twice after Tomato, versus only once after apple.

I was thinking about having an object, that has the all the fruits as Keys, and having an array as property of each fruit, the index of the array would be the number of times it has been used (or the position), so when input Tomato, I would call for the property of Tomato and the index would be the length, which would be the most used fruit after Tomato.

Using the input above, the object would be:

```
{Tomato=[Apple,Orange],Orange=[Tomate],Apple=[Tomato]}
```

Is this good practice? Are there better ways to do it?

I also have doubts regarding the indexing, how should I save and update it?

Is having a mirror object good practice? It would save in which index of each fruit is a particular fruit at, so I wouldn't have to do `for` loops in the Array, it can grow to hundreds of indexes in the array in each fruit.

As for the saving I would have a global array that pushed the fruits as they are entered, and every time there's a new entry I up the index of the current entered fruit, on the key of the previous entered.

Comment: With 17000 entries that work should be done *server-side*. What is your sever technology?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Oops, 17000 is on the other platform, this one is using 6000 entries. I use GAS - Google-apps-script, HTMLOutput, so the server technology is google hehe. Forgot to add the tag.

Comment: Anything over a few 100 should be handled server-side lest you bloat the page.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You mean I should send the server the variables, and get back the next suggestion? Server side with GAS is too costly in time and unreliable, it can take from millisecond to several seconds for each call, for a single string to return.This wouldn't make for a nice responsiveness.

Comment: That is standard auto-complete behaviour for large lists. Large lists on the browser are a sure way to kill browser performance. If it takes "several seconds" you need new hosting! :) You return all matches in one go. Single requests, all matching results (+ your most used at the top).

Comment: You *could* store just the most-used entries client side as that is a small list.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Here's a 10.000 implementation autocomplete, I see no problem in responsiveness, the field is "Nome Datasul". We all use only chrome, always updated. https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzfB0v1u_ex4J5ANVYIZYe80h2rh-bXSQVclvM056ypKAMvcAXY/exec

Comment: That's fantastic... *If everyone uses your browser* :)

Comment: Data structures aside make sure you set the option 'sortResults:false' jQuery autocomplete will try to sort the results after you load them. I would also keep data you needs handy in cache instead of reading from the SS everytime.  Just doing that is about 100% speed-up.

Comment: @SpencerEaston Strange the sortResults, cause nothing is sorted, until I specify so with the default Javascript sort, will add tough. I keep my vars in a file as a string, then parse as JSON, the servers converts the JSON to Array and return it to the client side, will look into caching it.